# why can I not get the groups I joined using long-term access_token (Facebook)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Graph API explorer, I can get the access token and using it, I can get my groups. But when I use my long-term access token, I cannot get my group information. What is wrong ?

I checked the permissions of the long-term access token by using:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/permissions?access_token={long-term access token}

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "user_friends",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have `user_groups` granted to that long lived access token.

You can check by querying `/me/permissions`

You can grant access by checking the following link

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_OF_YOUR_APP_HERE&scope=user_groups`

Comment: But why can I get the group information using the short-lived-access_token from Graph API explorer ?Thanks

Comment: @tqjustc Because you granted `user_groups` permission to the Explorer at one point in time. You can check by querying `/me/permissions` as I said earlier.

Comment: I added the result of the permission.

Comment: @tqjustc file a bug. developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: sorry, phwd,  This is the result of my long term access token. I get this by using my previous short term access token

Comment: Do you how to grant permission to the long-term access token ? thanks very much

Comment: @tqjustc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#adding `https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_OF_YOUR_APP_HERE&scope=user_groups`